# How to always show last page of the UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

i am  using `UIWebview` as a console  page for particular downloading process ,i want to show last line or last page of UIWebview like console. so please tell any methods there for that.i am adding text to `UIWebview` different places using following code `[webView loadHTMLString:theApp.consoleUpdaterStr baseURL:nil];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set `contentOffset`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not working, i am adding text to webview different places using following code [webView loadHTMLString:theApp.consoleUpdaterStr baseURL:nil];

Comment: Make sure you have written in webViewDidFinishLoad.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, myWebview.scrollView.contentSize.height - myWebview.scrollView.bounds.size.height);

[myWebview.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX);
}
```